# How to simulate mouse click?

Tags: vb.net, mouseevent, mouse

I'm trying to make a program to click with keyboard like in [Osu!](http://osu.ppy.sh).

I've tried `SendKeys()`, `RaiseMouseEvent()` and `OnMouseClick()`. Now I'm trying this and can't get anything to work.

The error I keep getting is:

> [PInvoke restriction: cannot return variants.](http://puu.sh/3tBQb.png)

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim onn As Boolean = False
    Declare Function mc Lib "user32.dll" Alias "mouse_event" (flag, x, y, button, extra)
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If Not onn Then
            Button1.Text = "Off"
            Label1.Text = "Status: On"
            onn = True
        ElseIf onn Then
            Button1.Text = "On"
            Label1.Text = "Status: Off"
            onn = False
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_KeyPress1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
        If onn And (e.KeyChar = "Z" Or e.KeyChar = "X" Or e.KeyChar = "z" Or e.KeyChar = "x") Then
            mc(&H2, 0, 0, 0, 0)
            mc(&H4, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This examples clicks where the mouse currently is when the feature is in the "onn" state:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private onn As Boolean = False

    Private Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Integer, _
      ByVal dx As Integer, ByVal dy As Integer, ByVal cButtons As Integer, _
      ByVal dwExtraInfo As Integer)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.KeyPreview = True
        Button1.Text = "Off"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        onn = Not onn
        Button1.Text = IIf(onn, "On", "Off")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_KeyPress1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
        If onn Then
            Select Case e.KeyChar
                Case "Z", "z", "X", "x"
                    mouse_event(&H2, 0, 0, 0, 0)
                    mouse_event(&H4, 0, 0, 0, 0)

            End Select
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Debug.Print("Button2")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Debug.Print("Button3")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: That moves the cursor to the button right?. That's not what I'm trying to do. I don't want to click the button with the mouse. The button turns it on. I want to click other stuff when I hit z or x just as if I hit the mouse button. For example if I moved the mouse over "Add Comment" right now and hit z or x It would click it as if I clicked with mouse.

Comment: If you want to click things with the mouse_event() API then you either have to move the mouse first and click with zeroes as the parameter (as in your example), or you have to specify actual coordinates to click at.  My example puts the cursor back where it was after performing the click.  So if you want to "click other stuff" then move the mouse over that other stuff, perform the click, then put the mouse back...

Comment: I don't want to move the mouse with the code. I want it to click where it is.

Comment: Oh...your original code was almost there then.  As I said, using zeroes for the parameters clicks where the cursor currently is.  I tested and it worked fine for me.  I'll post my test code above...

Comment: Did you see the link to the picture I added at the top? It shows what it says when I try it...

Comment: Are you using **MY** code?  Look closely as I corrected the signature for that API.

Comment: That's a whole different ballgame.  To trap the keystrokes while your program is NOT selected you'd have to use a low level keyboard hook via WH_KEYBOARD_LL.  Google it or ask another question...

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Class Iconform

  Public Declare Auto Function SetCursorPos Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer) As Long

  Public Declare Auto Function GetCursorPos Lib "User32.dll" (ByRef lpPoint As Point) As Long

  Public Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" Alias "mouse_event" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)

  Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2 ' left button down

  Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4 ' left button up

  Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = &H20 ' middle button down

  Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = &H40 ' middle button up

  Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = &H8 ' right button down

  Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = &H10 ' right button up



  Private Sub NotifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles NotifyIcon1.Click

    SettingsForm.Show()



  End Sub



  Private Sub OptionsToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OptionsToolStripMenuItem.Click

    SettingsForm.Show()

  End Sub



  Private Sub CloseToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CloseToolStripMenuItem.Click

    Me.Close()



  End Sub

  Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown

    Dim bHandled As Boolean = False

    Dim xPos As Integer = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X.ToString

    Dim zPos As Integer = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y.ToString



    Select Case e.KeyCode

      Case Keys.Right

        Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = New Point(xPos + 10, zPos)

      Case Keys.Left

        Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = New Point(xPos - 10, zPos)

      Case Keys.Down

        Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = New Point(xPos, zPos + 10)

      Case Keys.Up

        Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = New Point(xPos, zPos - 10)

      Case Keys.D

        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)







    End Select

  End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `PerformClick()` method:

```
Button1.PerformClick()
```

In your code it could be like:

```
If onn And (e.KeyChar = "Z" Or e.KeyChar = "X" Or e.KeyChar = "z" Or e.KeyChar = "x") Then

    Button1.PerformClick()
End If
```

Comment: I just tried it and that's not what I'm trying to do. That clicks the button. The button is supposed to turn it on and then the keys z and x are supposed to click like if I clicked the left mouse button.