# Perform a left mouse click in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, events, click, mouse

for my tool I need to simulate a left click. Moving the mouse to the point where the button is works with this simple code:

```
Cursor.Position = New Point(1275, 502)
```

Afterwards, I need to left click on that position

Is there a way this easy to simulate a mouse click too? I've read a lot of "user32.dll", but didn't get how to use it and why you even need it. Isn't there a simpler way?

Thanks in advance!

I know that this isn't really a neat solution, but in my environment, this will work pretty well.

Comment: There's nothing built into Windows Forms that allows you to simulate an arbitrary click.  Why would there be?  You do indeed have to use pinvoke to call a Windows API function, so you had better learn how.

Comment: [PInvoke.net](https://pinvoke.net/) has examples for quite a few such things. Or do you want to perform clicks inside your own program?

Comment: PInvoking is not actually necessary, you can use UI Automation to Invoke the default action of a Button, no matter what Application owns the Window that has that Button as a child. Works with both WPF Windows/Elements and Win32 Forms/Controls. See the [AutomationElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automationelement) class and the [InvokePattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.invokepattern) class [Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.invokepattern.invoke) method.

Comment: Thank you for your anwers. I need to perform the click inside my own Windows Form, over a WebBrowser. The location is defined by it's x- and y-axes. I will take a look at PInvoke

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to simulate mouse click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17414301/how-to-simulate-mouse-click)